# Ansible sx su - impersonation

Tags: ansible, impersonation, su

Does anybody have an idea how to execute a playbook on a RHEL machine with sx su - impersonation?

Ansible only provides sudo out of the box but we cannot use sudo as we are using Boks ssh. 
Does anybody have an idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible privilege escalation is documented: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

It mentions you cannot combine methods.

Comment: Can you share how the boks configuration (sx su - <user>) looks like, am still not able to figure it out. Also how the password is supplied for the <user>

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can!
Ansible.cfg has a flax where you can use sx su as a become method